# Cross Power Spectral Density of Unevenly Sampled Data

Tags: discrete-signals, cross-correlation, power-spectral-density

Here's my problem. The input signals $x$ and $y$ will be having the time value aligned with each other. However, the data are not evenly sampled. I would like to calculate CPSD of both signals.

The solution comes to my mind is as follow

1. $R_{xy}$ = cross correlation of $x$ and $y$ (I'm not sure how to do it with unevenly sampled data)
2. Use Lomb Periodogram to estimate the CPSD of Rxy

Is there anything I miss? And what is the right way to do it?

**Update**

Sam Maloney suggested to use interpolation to fill the gap to produce evenly sampled data. 
This solution is good.

However, the data I obtained may have some missing data / long gap. Interpolating the data may "predict" the data wrongly and produce undesired end result.

As quoted in [Numerical Recipes (Spectral Analysis of Unevenly Sampled
Data)](http://www.mpi-hd.mpg.de/astrophysik/HEA/internal/Numerical_Recipes/f13-8.pdf)

> However, the experience of practitioners of such interpolation techniques is not reassuring. Generally speaking, such techniques perform poorly. Long gaps in the data, for example,
>   often produce a spurious bulge of power at low frequencies (wavelengths comparable to gaps)

This is the reason why I choose Lomb Periodogram over FFT in **Step 2** without interpolating the data. However, I'm unable to figure out how to solve the **Step 1**. Is there any way to calculate the cross correlation of 2 signals without interpolating them?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to interpolate the signals to produce evenly-spaced samples and then calculate the CPSD as normal.